# Require double click to make edit on Bootstrap form. Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

My goal is to make the end user double clicks the red area to edit text, and to click the save button to stop the edit function.

I am been doing research on how to do this. However, I am not having much luck.  Am I looking at this wrong or is the answer easier than I am making it?

I have gone through bootstrap docs, not finding anything there. I have also searched hot to mae form double click to edit, no luck with that.

```js
$( ".am9Input" ).dblclick(function() {
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block{
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06AED5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;

}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
   
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Work Day Scheduler</title>
  </head>
   
  <body>
    <header class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
      <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
      <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Timeblocks go here -->
     
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-2 hour'> 9am
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-8 description red border-bottom">
          <input class="border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent am9Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 saveBtn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 am9Button">Save</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
   
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that by listening to the `double_clicks` on the input element and `clicks` on the button. 
Change the line
`<input class="border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent am9Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">` ---> `<input class="border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent am9Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input" readonly>` and also edit your `script.js` file by adding the snippet below and it should do the trick.

```js
$( ".am9Input" ).dblclick(function() {
 $(".am9Input").attr("readonly", false); 
 });

$( ".am9Button" ).click(function() {
 $(".am9Input").val(""); 
 $(".am9Input").attr("readonly", true); 
 });
```

Additionally, as a comment, I suggest using id's rather than classes for identifying the elements on your page that have click events for you might run into problems if you keep using classes for this specific purpose. You can read up on [Classes vs ID's here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) if you are interested.